# How to connect a local network to IPv6 site / net?

Tags: linux, ipv6, 6to4

I want to connect my home network (IPv4 only conection to internet) to my server (IPv4/IPv6), what is the best way to do this?

Current setup:

- Home network ("HOMENETWORK") with Linux (Ubuntu 14.04) router ("HOMEROUTER")
- DSL (PPPoE) connection, IPv4 only to the internet
- Hosted Server with IPv4 and IPv4 connection ("SERVER")
- Hosted server has single IPv6 address + whole /64 network routed to this address ("IPv6NETWORK")

I want to use the IPv6NETWORK for my HOMENETWORK, so I need to setup some tunnel between HOMEROUTER and SERVER. But how to do this?

**Is there any good tutorial?** Most howtos/tutorials only describe how to connect to one of these tunnel endpoints using the anycast IP 192.88.99.1.

I succeeded in setting up such a tunnel, but as this adds a lot of latency with my ISP, this is not the solution I prefer.

**What is necessary to make SERVER able to be a 6to4 endpoint?**

Furthermore I want to have static address for some of my endpoints within HOMENETWORK, so it will be easy to connect from SERVER (or any other IPv6 endpoint) to the endpoint within HOMENETWORK. (Finally get rid of all that NAT mess! :-) )

Comment: Change ISPs to one that supports v6 natively.  It's painful, sure, and will probably cost you more, but it's the only thing that will send a message to the big ISPs that v6 is needed for end-users, **now**.

Comment: Don't use 6to4. It is not the appropriate protocol for what you want. Do both sides have fixed, public IPv4 addresses? In that case you can use a 6in4 tunnel between the server and your home router.